# Automating sorting process for files in a folder based on same prefixes in their filenames

Tags: applescript, automator, script, file, macos

Okay, I have a directory that is the output directory for generated screenshots for a media player I use on a macbook (OS X High Sierra). I take a multitude of screenshots to review video files and I have a string system in the media player that names those screenshots in a certain format.

So my directory often fills up with hundreds or thousands of files, as the media player is unable to dynamically create an appropriate directory for output per video filename.

The filenames are formatted like so:

"[originalvideofilename.ext] [(##*##*##)]_[#####].jpg"

Obviously the square brackets are just to illustrate the way the media player generates the string. First, the original video's filename in full including the original extension. Second, after a space, is a timecode in (00_00_00) format. Finally, an underscore separates the previous from a 5-digit sequential index number with leading zeroes.

And depending on the source file, that filename might have spaces, periods or underscores in the filename, all rendered as is in the screenshot output filename, with a mix of uppercase or lowercase letters and the formats could be mp4, mkv, etc.

So the screenshot output directory might look like this:

- JPG Screenshots

  - Alternate Cut Sound Take 3.MP4 (00_00_15)_00001.jpg
  - Alternate Cut Sound Take 3.MP4 (00_00_17)_00002.jpg
  - Angle breakdown 1080p.mkv (00_03_58)_00064.jpg
  - Review Draft Footage Edit v3.MOV (00_01_30)_00001.jpg
  - Review Draft Footage Edit v3.MOV (00_01_36)_00002.jpg

My problem is that at the end of a day of reviewing footage, I'd like to be able to run an Automator workflow or application that does the following:

1. Looks at the .jpg files in the selected directory (output folder for the screenshots)
2. Determines the [videofilename.ext] part of the filenames of however many files are in there
3. Creates subfolders in an different output directory per unique "[videofilename.ext]"
4. Moves the .jpg files into their appropriate subfolders.
5. Leaving the source directory empty.

If the above tasks were automated with the click of a button, coded in such a way as to not get caught up on the differing cases, original filename extensions (end of the prefix part of the resultant .jpg files' filenames), or varying uses of periods, underscores, spaces or a mix thereof in the original filenames.

I suppose if it were necessary going forward I could alter the screenshot output to have a specific separator in between the three different components of the filename.

But the real problem is coding something flexible that can take the input of the folder full of jpg files and sort them for me automatically cause I'm sick of doing it manually.

So a resulting output folder structure would look like this:

- Sorted JPGs

  1. Alternate Cut Sound Take 3.MP4

     - Alternate Cut Sound Take 3.MP4 (00_00_15)_00001.jpg
     - Alternate Cut Sound Take 3.MP4 (00_00_17)_00002.jpg
  2. Angle breakdown 1080p.mkv

     - Angle breakdown 1080p.mkv (00_03_58)_00064.jpg
  3. Review Draft Footage Edit v3.MOV

     - Review Draft Footage Edit v3.MOV (00_01_30)_00001.jpg
     - Review Draft Footage Edit v3.MOV (00_01_36)_00002.jpg

I had a look around online and nobody seems to have quite the same situation as my setup, and no examples I found were easily modifiable for this use.

I'm a complete coding newbie, obviously I come from the video side of things and have technical knowledge in that arena. Sorry if I've not given enough information or explained my needs clearly. Let me know and I can ammend this post or provide more info.

Is there anyone that has an idea about how I should address this particular problem?

Comment: Is there ever a `(` in the `[videofilename.ext]` part?

Comment: Please add what you have already come up with. We are happy to help you figure out issues with your Applescript, but you need to at least take a first pass at the problem.